# https на движке Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, apache, nginx, https

Возникла проблемка небольшая с движком wordpress

Имеется сайт на wordpress движке который доступен и отлично работает по http и https открываются все страницы. Тоесть полный рабочий функционал

Я желаю сделать так чтобы сайт uniquest.uz открывался только по https тоесть происходила переадресация, однако все мои попытки пока не увенчаются успехом

Как только я прописываю в htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

На сайте перестают работать внутренние ссылки, главная страница открывается нормально, как быть, и почему так происходит

P/s/

Адрес WordPress (URL)    http://uniquest.uz

Адрес сайта (URL)    http://uniquest.uz

Если поставить https все ломается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы WordPress сайт работал правильно на `https`, надо сделать следующее:

1. Вписать `https` как в `Адрес WordPress (URL)`, так и в `Адрес сайта (URL)`. В вашем случае должно быть `https://uniquest.uz`
2. Заменить `http://` на `https://` во всех внутренних ссылках в базе. Это нельзя делать заменой по текстовому дампу базы, поскольку в этом случае сериализованные данные будут повреждены. Лучше всего воспользоваться [DATABASE SEARCH AND REPLACE SCRIPT IN PHP](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)
3. Поставить такие правила в Apache:

:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: А мой сайт тогда на мобильниках не откроется,

Comment: Это с чего бы? Мой-то открывается. Я ж не с потолка совет даю - кроме своего сайта еще и множество клиентских переводил на https

Comment: соглашусь пожалуй с вами ....  только вопросик появился почему когда в настройках wordpress был http, сайт работал прекрасно и на https (единственный минус небыло авто переадресации с http на https), но вручную все работало

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, что такое вручную. Как-то WP может работать и при частично правильной конфигурации. При этом запросто на многих страницах может быть mixed content и т.п. Если хотим, чтобы все было правильно, тогда вот по перечню выше.

Comment: вручную значит работал весь функционал на http и https, но не было переадресации на https. Я мог вручную набрать адрес сайта с https и он отлично работал

Comment: https://uniquest.uz/o-nas 404 not found все ссылки заменил этой прогой, проверил все отлично http: больше нет, но внутренние линки htaccess не работают

Comment: что такое внутренние линки htaccess

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54801/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-anton).

Comment: да можно я уже зашел

Answer (score 0):

Правь nginx конфиг. файл, который будет открывать определенный сайт, по определенному домену. А так же в самом WP переделай ссылки на поддержку WP

Comment: Какой nginx? У него apache

Comment: "А так же в самом WP переделай ссылки на поддержку WP" за такими перлами  баш плачет :)

Answer (score 0):

Все проблему решил всегото нужно было

Адрес WordPress (URL) http://*****.uz

Адрес сайта (URL) https://*****.uz

и линки тоже на https:

Comment: Этого мало - нужен более широкий перечень действий, как описано в моем ответе

Comment: да согласен некоторые линки работают с переадресацией на https а некоторые в осадок, остаются в http