# WordPress отображает стили не во всех браузерах

Tags: wordpress, cms

Всем привет.
Сайт на этапе разработке. Посажен на WordPress с woocommerce. В какой то момент перестал отображать стили. Причём происходит это не во всех браузерах. И не понятно от чего зависит. У меня отображает только в Opera, а в хроме даже в инкогнито нет стилей. На другом ноуте не отображает ни в одном браузере, при этом в админку пускает везде и админку отображает, но даже в админ режиме отображает сайт без стилей.
Перепробовал наверное все. И не пойму от чего этого зависит.
Сайт exquisit12.ru
Помогите

Comment: У Вас в консоли 30+ ошибок, туда заглядывать не пробовали?

Comment: Суть в том, что в опере как раз без них открывает. Но это у меня. У вас значит тоже с ошибками. Именно это и не могу понять почему

Comment: Потому что Mixed Content? Там же написано: `The page at 'https://exquisit12.ru/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://exquisit12.ru/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/elementor/css/custom-frontend-lite.min.css?ver=6.2.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` и так далее.

Comment: А можно пояснение, о чем это говорит?

Comment: Точнее как это решить можно?

Comment: Точнее как это решить можно.? Ssl подключён на домен

Comment: [https на движке Wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635435/https-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b5-wordpress). [Ну и в интернетах поискать можно](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=move+wordpress+site+from+http+to+https)

Comment: Решил установкой плагина really simple ssl. Спасибо за совет и ответ

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в смешанной содержимом. Решилась установкой плагина really simple ssl

Comment: Это плохое решение. Нужно менять ссылки в базе. И менять правильно. Например с пом https://wordpress.org/plugin/better-search-replace/